# How to delete lines containing only numbers in BASH?

Tags: bash

I have a TXT file. How can I delete only those lines which only contain numbers. For e.g.:

```
This has some text.
1300
This has some more text.
1210
This has a text and some numbers. 12
```

In the sample above, only lines 2 and 4 would be deleted as they are the ones that contain no other symbols besides numbers.

Comment: `sed -i -e '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/d' file-to-munge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grep:

```
grep -v -E '^[0-9]+$' < source.txt > destination.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an awk solution:

```
awk '! /^[0-9]+$/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed solution (will overwrite the file):

```
sed -i '/^[[:digit:]]*$/d' filename.TXT
```